# Databinding ItemsControl (DataTemplate) not updating /only receives values on program start up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

**EDIT2:** When the chart gets populated i am unable to change the values anymore. Even when i change the values in the list (where the ItemControls get the values from) the chart does not seem to update with the new values.

I call upon the GetDataGrafiek() method in the timer to update my chart every x seconds.

```
        Grafiek graf = new Grafiek();
        graf.GetDataGrafiek();
```

Is this due the Threading Timer running in a separate thread(`IsAsynchronous` method in the `ObjectDataProvider`) or do i need to access the `DataContext` of the ItemsControl in my timer method?

**EDIT:** I was unable able to populate the chart when the program was already running so i made the `ObservableCollection<GrafiekBar>` static (list that holds the Fill and Value of the bars) and initialized is as following:

```
public static ObservableCollection<GrafiekBar> listGrafiek = new ObservableCollection<GrafiekBar>()
        {
            new GrafiekBar() {Value = 0, Fill = (Brush)convertor.ConvertFromString(kleuren[0])},
            new GrafiekBar() {Value = 0, Fill = (Brush)convertor.ConvertFromString(kleuren[1])},
            new GrafiekBar() {Value = 0, Fill = (Brush)convertor.ConvertFromString(kleuren[2])}
        };
```

From MSDN: *ObjectDataProvider: "However, if you are binding to an object that has already been created, you need to set the DataContext in code, as in the following example."*

---

I have a ItemsControl that is being displayed as a simple bar chart. 
When i assign values (*hardcoded in my codeBehind*) the chart gets populated succesfully.

What i do is basically getting the largest value set it to 100% and calculate the length of the rest of the bars trough that.

**Problem:** 
I do not want the chart bar values hardcoded but the bars have to change runTime.
For this i use a `Threading.Timer` that runs every second as long my program is running (other calculations happen in this timer as well).

*The chart bar values get updates based on the calculations happening within this timer every x seconds.*

I have tried everything and i cannot get values displayed when my program is running. I can only see bars when i hardcode them (see region of `GetDataGrafiek()` at the end of the thread). What exactly am i doing wrong / missing?

The  `GetDataGrafiek()` (calculations to populate my chart) gets called in a `ObjectDataProvider`.

This method takes TimeSpan as input and then performs calculations so i get a Double Value (based on the 100% value explained above) which then gets placed in the Value of the bar (= width of the dateTemplate).

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpLbGrafiek" ObjectType="{x:Type myClasses:GrafiekBar}" MethodName="GetDataGrafiek"/>
```

**DataTemplate for my ItemsControl** (this uses the Width for the value of the bars of my chart)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GrafiekItemTemplate">
        <Border Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0" Height="30"  
                           Margin="15" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           Width="{Binding Value}"
                           Fill="{Binding Fill}">
                    <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="20" />
                    </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**ItemsControl:**

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="icGrafiek"  
            Margin="50,3,0,0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpLbGrafiek}}"
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GrafiekItemTemplate}" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="6">
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="1"/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        </ItemsControl>
```

**GetDataGrafiek()** The region holds hardcoded values, when this is done my chart displays 6 bars succesfully. When i comment the region i no longer get any visible bars.

This method returns a list with `Double` values. Each value represents a bar that gets represented as Width in the `DataTemplate`, and the Fill just gives it a certain color.

```
ObservableCollection<GrafiekBar> listGrafiek = new ObservableCollection<GrafiekBar>();

    public ObservableCollection<GrafiekBar> GetDataGrafiek()
    {
        var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();

        #region ***TEST HARDCODED BAR VALUES*** 
            int[] testWaardenUren = new int[] { 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0 };
            int[] testWaardenMinuten = new int[] { 58, 2, 55, 55, 2, 20 };

            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(testWaardenUren[j], testWaardenMinuten[j], 0);
                GlobalObservableCol.regStilstanden[j].Value = ts;
                GlobalObservableCol.regStilstanden[j].Name = "";
            }
        #endregion

        totalMinutesMaxValue = GetLargestValueStilstanden(); //= "100%" value

        //calculate % of stilstanden Values
        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalObservableCol.regStilstanden.Count; i++)
        {
            Double totalMin = GlobalObservableCol.regStilstanden[i].Value.TotalMinutes;
            totalMin = totalMin / totalMinutesMaxValue * 10; 
            valuesChartPercentage.Add(totalMin);
        }

        //the barChart (itemsControl) gets its final values here
        for (int j = 0; j < GlobalObservableCol.regStilstanden.Count; j++)
        {
            GrafiekBar bar = new GrafiekBar();
            bar.Value = valuesChartPercentage[j];
            bar.Fill = converter.ConvertFromString(kleuren[j]) as Brush;
            listGrafiek.Add(bar);
        }

        return listGrafiek;
    }
```

**GrafiekBar.cls**

```
 public class GrafiekBar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double value;
    private Brush fill;

    public GrafiekBar()
    {      
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }

        set
    {
            this.value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get { return this.fill; }

        set
        {
            this.fill = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Fill");
        }
    }

    //interface INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //interface INotifyPropertyChanged
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

The Threading timer that runs every second (that has the calculation logic and the getDataGrafiek() called there does a invoke to the GUI thread for updates.

```
private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();

        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                //actions that involve updating the UI
                CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen();
            }));
    }
```

*Best Regards Peter.*

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're doing here, but having a timer running sounds super weird. Can't you respond to events instead?

Comment: The chart has to change (or not change if not required) based on calculations that are happening every second in that timer. I am not really sure how to solve this.

Comment: Just a rough guess: Have you tried using DispatcherTimer instead of a normal Timer. This timer was optimized for WPF dispatching

Comment: @SvenG Yes Sven but that resulted in lag and heavy performance issues (on the UI thread) so that is not a option. I made some edits on top of my post what i am currently attempting to try and solve this issue.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but in the GetDataGrafiek method, if you comment out the hardcoded values region, how is GlobalObservableCol populated to perform the calculations?

Comment: That is being calculated in the Calculate method within the threading timer that runs every 5 seconds.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can get answers much faster if you isolate the problem and post here the minimal code required to replicate the problem. Copy/pasting the entire production code just seems lazy, I'm sure the problem can be simplified and the number of lines of code can be reduced.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you mean, i just have a hard time figuring whats exactly the problem. Tried to size down my post and describe what i think is the current problem.

Comment: Above you are setting the ObjectDataProvider x:key to: "odpLbGrafiek" but I never see you actually set the datacontext anywhere to that. On the grid maybe set: <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpLbGrafiek}}" ...something like this anyway

Comment: This might have been mentioned somewhere before, but wouldn't make more sense to just bind the chart to a property and and use ComponentModel.IPropertyChanged?  Since you're doing this inside of another thread, you'll probably need to raise the propertychanged event asynchroniously on the Dispatcher thread, but in my experience, doing this is a lot easier (and cleaner) most of the time then dealing with IValueConverters.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark, 'cause I did not read through all your code, but here's a thought: you are binding to a static resource right? It gets read once and this is it, eh? Try DynamicResource instead.

Comment: Ah, never mind, that was a stupid idea. What does exactly CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen(); do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the following code from another thread, this will cause an issue:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

As the other thread will raise an event which will cause the Dispatcher Thread (if it's subscribed to the event) to error.

Try instead

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread == System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        else
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you are using UpdateSourceMethod=PropertyChanged in WPF.

Comment: Also, one thing I didn't really quite understand is what is the purpose of handler.  If you're binding directly from WPF, you don't need handler, just UpdateSourceMethod=PropertyChanged in the data bind in XAML.